# How to plot a satellite trace wrt a ground station using polar plot view?

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, polar-coordinates

I have a [ground station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_station) which is tracking a satellite. I have the [Azimuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth) & [Elevation](http://www.radartutorial.eu/01.basics/Measurement%20of%20the%20elevation%20angle.en.html) angles of this trace per second. I want to visualize this using a [polar plot](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/control_systems/control_systems_polar_plots.htm) which would indicate the trace of the satellite. How to do it correctly?

How do I convert these angles into coordinates of a polar plot? I searched the web for possible answers but couldn't find anything meaningful. I found a MATLAB function "polar" but it only takes one angle as input (novice, so I maybe wrong about this).

```
Elevation   Azimuth
11.31693268 19.14014857
12.69233985 19.52583539
14.1401434  19.94125872
15.66863156 20.39098266
17.28724858 20.88052782
19.00675835 21.41663385
20.83941898 22.00761262
22.79915889 22.66383037
24.90173605 23.39837633
27.16484691 24.22800675
29.60812765 25.17450351
32.25295023 26.26667162
35.1218531  27.54334561
38.23734641 29.05803185
41.61967464 30.88627821
45.28287159 33.13771907
49.228037   35.97633442
53.43205048 39.65532946
57.61559325 45.56022473
```

Here are some sample values in degrees. I want to convert these values into a trace on a polar plot. I would also like to do this using MATLAB, so help regarding that would be appreciated too.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. If this is real data you might want to mention the source of the data.  However, I think what you want might be $\tan\left(\frac\pi4-\frac{\text{elevation}}2\right)(\sin(\text{azimuth}),\cos(\text{azimuth}))$. This gives the [Stereographic Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).

Comment: This is real data for a satellite pass over the ground station. I am afraid I can't give the source as this sample is part of the test data of satellite cluster with a confidentiality agreement

Comment: Here is the function I used to massage your data into the $(\theta,r)$ form used by `ListPolarPlot` in Mathematica: `f[{elev_,az_}] := {Pi/2+Pi/180 az,Tan[Pi/4-Pi/360 elev]}`. Then applying `ListPolarPlot` and adding a horizon (the circle) and other labels, we get [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElMdh.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More context has been added to the question, so I feel it appropriate to expand on my comments.

I don't have MATLAB, so I will use Mathematica functionality, and hopefully, that can be translated to MATLAB functionality.

---

First, to plot elevation ($\varepsilon$) and azimuth ($\alpha$) into standard polar coordinates, I would use the [Stereographic Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) rotated so that an azimuth of $0$ is north, $\theta=\frac\pi2$:
$$
\begin{align}
r&=\tan\left(\frac\pi4-\frac\varepsilon2\right)\\
\theta&=\frac\pi2+\alpha
\end{align}\tag1
$$
Applying this conversion, as well as the conversion from degrees to radians, the following function gives the polar coordinates $(\theta,r)$ that can be passed to `ListPolarPlot`:

`f[{elev_,az_}] := {Pi/2+Pi/180 az,Tan[Pi/4-Pi/360 elev]}`

Adding some decorations, I get the following visualization:

[image]

The circle is the horizon and the grey lines intersect at the zenith.

Comment: @amWhy: I waited to answer until the OP improved their question. Once the question seemed to have reasonable context, I tried to write an answer that would benefit not only the OP, but also others. I hope that the formulas in $(1)$ are applicable in cases outside this question.

Comment: The stereographic projection is what most astronomy programs use when displaying the sky (both entire and partial).

Comment: I understand that this question has been the subject of a heated discussion on meta. However, either due to that discussion or some prompting here in comments, the question has been improved (context was added in the form of the source of the question and definitions of the terms used). I saw the question as one of how one might convert the elevation and azimuth data to polar coordinates ([tag:trigonometry]). It also asked, if possible, how to do this in MATLAB, but that seemed to be a secondary, but reasonable, request given that MATLAB is software that mathematicians use ([tag:matlab]).

Comment: In spite of these improvements, the question remains highly downvoted. My answer, although I waited until the question was improved to post, and edited it to remove most of the code, is twice downvoted.

Comment: some people got to my 1 other question on this community & started downvoting that too. Anyway, part & parcel of heated debate. I don't mind as long as I get my answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want  [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) (because the motion is in a 3D space). I suppose that your ''Elevation'' is the complementary angle of the polar angle.

Comment: I dont want a 3D plot. Although the Satellite track is in 3D, I want it projected onto a 2D plane

Comment: If you know the 3D spherical coordinates you can project on a given plane using stereographic projection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection

Comment: I dont have range 'r'. I only have Azimuth & Elevation. How can I convert them to spherical coordinate system. Can you explain me that

Comment: @KharoBangdo How to you want to project the sphere onto the plane?

Comment: @Phira [I suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820373/how-to-plot-a-satellite-trace-wrt-a-ground-station-using-polar-plot-view#comment5829823_2820373) a [Stereographic Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) and even provided [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElMdh.png). That didn't get a response, so I don't know if that is what is wanted.

Comment: @robjohn I didn't respond because I was looking at Stereographic Projection. It's a new term to me. That is in fact the kind of plot I wanted. But I was reading up how it was done hence did not respond